# Android - Draw bitmap as one color

Tags: android

I have several bitmaps (game sprites) which I'd like to draw into another bitmap, however each non-transparent pixel of the source bitmap should be drawn using a single color, ignoring the original pixel color of the source.  Basically, I'm trying to use the sprite as a "stamp" of a single color to be drawn into the destination bitmap.

I believe I should be using canvas.drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Matrix matrix, Paint paint), however I'm not exactly sure how I should initialize the paint object.  Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need to perform as many steps as Romain Guy suggests, just initialize your paint with the desired color, and use `Paint.setColorFilter()` with `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP`

```
myPaint.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(myColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));
```

Answer (score 1):

If your destination bitmap is transparent, draw all your sprites inside that bitmap normally (you can use a null Paint.) Then, draw a filled rectangle that covers the entire bitmap, using the Porter-Duff xfermode called SrcIn (Source In.)